# Is it grammatical to say "... is both popular and has presented ...'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

This particular example comes from a peer-reviewed publication with authors who seem to be native speakers:

> This trend is both popular and has presented a variety of challenges

I wonder if this is grammatical?

---

If this sentence didn't have *"both"*, we would parse it as follows:

> This trend ((is popular) and (has presented a variety of challenges))

But with *"both"*, what do we have?

> This trend is both ((popular) and (has presented a variety of challenges))

but this gives us "is has presented", so this parsing is incorrect. Alternatively, we could try

> This trend ((is both popular) and (has presented a variety of challenges)).

but then *"both"* goes **inside** the first coordinate. This is different from, say,

> You and me both

where it's at the end.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149711/discussion-on-question-by-mwb-is-it-grammatical-to-say-is-both-adjective-and-ve); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @Lambie - it was migrated; ELL [rejected](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/614706/timeline#history_83f28ddd-558d-42c5-a5f8-63c1dbc74671) it for some reason.

Comment: @Heartspring I think it should go back there. Thanks though for letting me know.

Comment: @Heartspring The current two answers state that this is grammatical. But of the comments that are now in "chat", some opined that this is ungrammatical. So the answer isn't obvious. This question isn't ELL-level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Huddleston & Pullum (2002) note, while *both* and *either* typically occur at the start the first coordinate in a coordination, they don't *necessarily* do so (p. 1307). They give the example:

> Usually he is either too busy to come with us or else has no money.

They say that "placement in these non-basic positions is quite common, particularly with *either*, though usage manuals tend to regard it as stylistically undesirable." I would agree on both points.

Comment: I don't think the issue is both. The issue is lack of parallelism in the sentence.

Comment: @Lambie The sentence doesn't have a lack of parallelism. The "and" in OP's example is joining "is popular" and "has presented a variety of challenges." It's just that the word "both" occurs *within* the first of those two.

Comment: "is popular" and "has presented x" is a complete lack of paralellism. With or without both, there is no paralellism. He is popular and rich. They ate chestnuts and drank beer. Those are parallel.

Comment: @Lambie Parallelism is a very stringent standard. Wikipedia gives this sentence as an example of LACKING parallelism: "The dog ran across the yard, jumped over the fence, and sprinted away." I think we can all agree that this sentence is fine even without parallelism?

Comment: @MWB For me that sentence you gave is parallel. Lack of parellelism is when the actual structure of the bits are different as in the given example. "X is popular" AND "Y has presented a variety of challenges".

Comment: @Lambie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)

Comment: @MWB What are you doing? Look at one of **their examples**: "She likes cooking, jogging, and reading." VERSUS "She likes cooking, jogging, and to read." That is very much like what we have here, for pete's sake. After 35 years editing, I think I know what parallelism is. My point was that in the OP's question the word both is the least of his/her/their worries. And I really fail to see how alphabet says the sentence has parallel structure. It simply does not.

Comment: @Lambie *"Look at one of their examples"* -- Maybe you should look at **all** of their examples? The one I quoted is number 3.

Comment: @MWB Of course, sprinted away has no object on the left. The two others **do** (yard and fence) **Ergo, no paralellism**. across the yard, over the fence and down the alley=makes for parallelism.

Comment: @Lambie *"Of course, sprinted away has no object. The two others do. Ergo, no paralellism."* -- Did you forget that you just wrote this: *"For me that sentence you gave is parallel."* Do you admit that you were wrong?

Comment: I think it is fine but it is not parallel, you are right. I was going too fast. But still I see you have not commented on the OP's question. Which is the whole point here, isn't it? Not determining something from Wikipedia to trip me  up when in fact **my first comment below the question is accurate**. How about you say something about that?

Answer (score -1):

Sample: This trend is both popular and has presented a variety of challenges.

Answer: Yes, it is grammatical.

A be verb (is) as copular followed by active verb with direct object. That is not parallelism

That sentence is both grammatical and unparallel.
You can remove the word both and it remains grammatical and unparallel.

Comment: Note that the question never asked about parallelism.

Comment: @MWB That's right it wasn't but it is the only thing that explains that both refers to both parts of the sentence. The trend is both A and B, A and B are not parallel. So what? He was both a nice man and loved to party. Same thing.

Comment: *"...the only thing that explains that both refers to both parts of the sentence"* --  The lack of parallelism allows "both" to refer to both parts of the sentence? I don't think this is true. Consider *"He was both easy to talk to and hard to disagree with"* This is parallel, while your *"He was both a nice man and loved to party."* wasn't. They are both grammatical. And both have "both" refer to both parts of the sentence.

Comment: @MWB You are twisting my words and I really dislike that. **The OP's sample sentence is grammatical but not parallel**. It's so simple really.